# How to use async/await with mongoose

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, error-handling, async-await

In node.js I had code like following:

```
mongoose.connect(dbURI, dbOptions)
.then(() => {
        console.log("ok");
    },
    err => { 
        console.log('error: '+ err)
    }
);
```

Now i want to do it with async/await syntax. So i could start with `var mcResult = await mongoose.connect(dbURI, dbOptions);`, afaik it will wait for operation, until it ends with any result (much like calling C function `read()` or `fread()` in syncronous mode).

But what should I write then? What does that return to the `mcResult` variable and how to check for an error or success? Basically I want a similar snippet, but written with proper async/await syntax.

Also I wonder because I have auto reconnect, among `dbOptions`:

```
dbOptions: {
  autoReconnect: true,
  reconnectTries: 999999999,
  reconnectInterval: 3000
}
```

Would it "stuck" on `await` forever, in case if database connection is unavailble? I hope you can give me a clue on what would happen and how that would work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Basically I want a similar snippet, but written with proper async/await syntax.

```js
(async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(dbURI, dbOptions)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('error: ' + err)
  }
})()
```

Comment: @xakepp35 Yes.  If you follow the logic through [`Connection.prototype.openUri`](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/connection.js#L526), you'll see that it eventually rejects.

Answer (score 6):

Please try this, Below code has basics of db connectivity and a query :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

const usersSchema = new Schema({
    any: {}
}, {
    strict: false
});

const Users = mongoose.model('users', usersSchema, 'users');

/** We've created schema as in mongoose you need schemas for your collections to do operations on them */

const dbConnect = async () => {
    let db = null;
    try {
        /** In real-time you'll split DB connection(into another file) away from DB calls */
        await mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }); // await on a step makes process to wait until it's done/ err'd out.
        db = mongoose.connection;

        let dbResp = await Users.find({}).lean(); /** Gets all documents out of users collection. 
                                   Using .lean() to convert MongoDB documents to raw Js objects for accessing further. */

        db.close(); // Needs to close connection, In general you don't close & re-create often. But needed for test scripts - You might use connection pooling in real-time. 
        return dbResp;
    } catch (err) {
        (db) && db.close(); /** Needs to close connection -
                   Only if mongoose.connect() is success & fails after it, as db connection is established by then. */

        console.log('Error at dbConnect ::', err)
        throw err;
    }
}

dbConnect().then(res => console.log('Printing at callee ::', res)).catch(err => console.log('Err at Call ::', err));
```

As we're talking about `async/await` then few things I wanted to mention - `await` definitely needs it's function to be declared as `async` - otherwise it would throw an error. And it's recommended to wrap `async/await` code inside `try/catch` block.

Answer (score 4):

```
const connectDb = async () => {
    await mongoose.connect(dbUri, dbOptions).then(
        () => {
            console.info(`Connected to database`)
        },
        error => {
            console.error(`Connection error: ${error.stack}`)
            process.exit(1)
        }
    )
}

connectDb().catch(error => console.error(error))
```

Lets assume the use of `then()` is prohibited, you can result to this...

```
const connectDb = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(dbConfig.url, dbConfigOptions)

        console.info(`Connected to database on Worker process: ${process.pid}`)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Connection error: ${error.stack} on Worker process: ${process.pid}`)
        process.exit(1)
    }
}
```